# How can I challenge OIDC to go to Login From Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having trouble to properly handle expired tokens when accessing my Web API. At the moment, it currently just throws a "401" status error when the token is expired and nothing more. But I need it to redirect to IdentityServer login to let the user login again.

Then I thought of intercepting the 401 error in API and force it to challenge IdentityServer with a middleware in the startup but it gives me the following exception

> No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: oidc

I need help on the right approach to achieve my aim here. This is what I tried in **Web API Startup.cs (Configure Method)**

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();

    if (context.User != null)
    {
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)
        {
            await context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
        }
    }
});
```

**N.B** I tried it also with `Bearer` but not luck as well.

Comment: Those are generally separate flows. If the client is directly communicating with the API, there should be an "auth" endpoint where it can transmit user/pass, client credentials, etc. and get a new access token back. If the client encounters a 401, then they should hit the auth endpoint again, and then retry their request. If you have a web app that's using this API, it should probably actually be connecting via client auth, irrespective of the user's actual login status, but if you're passing through the credentials, then you should catch the 401 response and redirect the user to login.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Are you saying I should catch the response in the client? If yes, I have no idea how to get it cos it doesn't throw that exception on the client sometimes. For instance, on the dashboard, if there's a 401 in the API, it will simple not show some data is supposed to get from the API but the view displays regardless. Can you guide me on how to implement your idea?

Comment: The API returning 401 is correct behaviour and it’s up to your client to deal with that. What sort of client app is it? There’s different ways of detecting and handling this condition depending on the topology.

Comment: Thanks Mackie. I know it's a normal behavior for the API. I just need it to redirect to Identity server to get the user to login again. The client is an MVC application.